# Computers causes other devices to lose network connection

Tags: networking, router, camera, connection

I have 6 IP cameras on my network. 2 of them (both plugged in via ethernet cable) lose connection to the network (can't be ping'd) every time I connect one PC to my network.  I've reached this conclusion by removing all the devices from my network and then adding them back, one by one, slowly testing to see if the cameras drop.

I tried to fix the problem by adding a new network card, but the problem still occurs.

All of the computers in my house use Windows 7 Home 64bit.

My network looks like this

Cable modem -> wireless router (A) -> 40 foot ethernet -> to wireless router (B) (connected Lan to Lan)

wireless router (A) connections:  one PC (trouble maker?), 1 wired IP cam (this one drops) wifi printer.
                    There is a wired connection to another switch: roku box, ip cam, Onlive micro console.

wireless router (B) connections:  one wired ip cam (this one drops), one wired NAS, one wired PC, 3 wireless ip cams.

I can't ssem to figure out how to keep the cameras from disconnecting.  Right now, I connected a wireless bridge to the PC that was connected to router (A) to keep it isolated and the cameras are not disconnecting.   I want to connect it via ethernet because I need the gigabit connection to my NAS from both PC's.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: What kind of IP addressing is in use? Can you (eventually) log into a camera and check its log?  Anything interesting in the router's log?

Comment: IP collisions perhaps?

Comment: I am using reserved IP's for each device, and they are all different.  The camera logs are garbage, they only tell who logged into them and when.  I normally use them with Blue Iris software. I should mention that if I unplug the ethernet cable and plug it back in, the connection will be re-established for another 10 minutes or so.

Comment: DHCP server is only running on the gateway router (A), no duplicate addresses.

Comment: Have you tried dropping the reserved address of the offending computer (making it use standard DHCP)?

Comment: Yes. Even if it's assigned a dynamic address, the same problem occurs.  My IT person at work thought it was a faulty network card, but after replacing it, the problem remained. I started to wonder if it was some kind of communication between the 2 pc's that was throwing the camera's off.  I tried, changing the ethernet ports they were connected to. No good.  If I connect them wirelessly instead, no problem, but I really need them wired.

Comment: try using static IPs instead of DHCP reservations.

Comment: Tried setting everything static.  Didn't help :(

Comment: Is it possible it is some sort of power issue?

Comment: It doesn't effect the devices until Windows is logged in on the suspect pc.  If I just leave it at the login prompt, no problem.  I can see the activity lights flashing on the NIC but, again, no problems until the pc is logged into an account.

Comment: After weeks of having this problem, I think the culprit was software that came with my motherboard...Intel IT Director.  As soon as I uninstalled it, the problem has disapperead.  I don't know how it was causing the problem, but I tried reinstalling it and the problem started happening again.

Answer (score 0):

Try turning the router B as access point and change the channel to 1 for the router A and 11 for Router B. Use different SSID for each of them. Let each device use alternate routers for connection. This way there will be less interference and should should resolve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Probe your network to see what MAC addresses and IP's are being used. Check what kind of traffic is going across your network. What kind of services, such as DHCP, DNS, RIP, etc, are being serviced by each router that might be causing conflicts of confusion?

Comment: This question is two years and OP has posted an answer in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

From OP's comment on the original question:

> After weeks of having this problem, I think the culprit was software that came with my motherboard... Intel IT Director. As soon as I uninstalled it, the problem has disapperead. I don't know how it was causing the problem, but I tried reinstalling it and the problem started happening again.